# XPath query for counting nodes

Tags: java, xpath

I want to use xpath to count occurances of certain node in xml document. What would I use? For ex: If I wanted to get second occurance of `movie` node I'd use `movie[2]`.

How do I get total number of movie node occurances in document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to use xpath to count occurances of certain node in xml document

Use [the `count` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count).

> The count function returns the number of nodes in the argument node-set

For your case, use this XPath expression:

```
count(//movie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `count(//movie)`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103.aspx for detail.

Comment: `count(movie)` will get evaluate to the number of `movie` childs of context node. Also, why did you not cite specs but MS documentation instead?